# Pyomo with Flask on Docker - No executable found for solver 'glpk'

Tags: docker, pyomo, glpk

This community helped me greatly in the past, so I'm turining to you again. I have a Pyomo model that I can successfully run on it's own locally. However, when I try to run it in docker container with Flask, it fails with the following error:

```
pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'glpk'.
```

My requirements.txt is:

```
flask
requests
simplejson
flask-cors
Pyomo
```

When I try to add glpk to requirements.txt, I get another error:

```
E: Unable to locate package glpk
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN mkdir /backend
WORKDIR /backend
COPY requirements.txt /backend/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I searched online for hours but nothing seems to help. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [glpk](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), in my case I do it with anaconda image. My example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN conda config --set channel_priority false
RUN conda update --all --yes
RUN conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 glpk
COPY . .
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/src"
CMD [ "python3", "src/app.py"]
```